# XML Parsing failure on Android but works on iPhone

Tags: android, xml-parsing, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

**Appcelerator Q&A Link:**
[XML Parsing failure on Android but works on iPhone](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/128341/xml-parsing-failure-on-android-but-works-on-iphone)

I am preparing a general application which works both for iPhone and Android phones with same code for which Titanium is majorly used for. With the same code I found different results for XML document parsing and my android app does not load it properly. It causes NULLPointer Exception. But the same code works perfectly on iPhone.

Can you check this?

```
xyz(languageCode, currentVersion, xmldoc) {
try {
  Ti.API.info('Start parsing the library');
  var archiveData = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('archive');
  Ti.API.info('Archive: ' + archiveData);
  Ti.API.info('Item: ' + archiveData.item);
  Ti.API.info('Lendth: ' + archiveData.length);
  var newVersion = archiveData.item(0).getAttribute('version');
}catch(e){
  Ti.API.info('Library Went In Catch: ' + e);
}
```

**Function call: It's from onload() method of Ti.Network.HttpClient**

> xyz(languageCode, version,this.responseXML.documentElement);

## Output of iPhone:

> Archive: [object TiDOMNodeList]
>
> [INFO] Item: [object TiDOMNodeList]
>
> [INFO] Lendth: 1

## Output of Android:

> [INFO] [3,7225] Archive: [Ti.NodeList]
>
> [INFO] [1,7226] Item: [KrollMethod item]
>
> [INFO] [2,7228] Lendth: 0 [INFO]
>
> [235,7466] Library Went In Catch: JavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the link:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/128341/xml-parsing-failure-on-android-but-works-on-iphone#comment-104281

For parsing XML using:

```
var xml = Ti.XML.parseString(this.responseXML.toString());

xyz(languageCode, version, xml);
```

"this.responseXML.documentElement". It has some problems on Android (don't know is it reported or not). The workaround it to use "Ti.XML.parseString" method to re-parse XML:.